# i2c scanner stuck on scanning for my 0.96in OLED screen with my Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c, display

[image: i2c scanner serial monitor]

> My pins are connected as follows; vcc-3v3, gnd-gnd, sda-A4, scl-A5.

Comment: Measure the voltage at SCL after the scan has been stuck. If it's LOW, the problem is probably the slave. Do you have external pullups?

Comment: no I don't have any pullup resistors on hand but do you think that could be the problem

Comment: I2C requires pullups, but sometimes, slaves already have them onboard. Can you measure the resistance between Vcc-SDA and Vcc-SCL? If it's larger than 10kOhm this can be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a 3.3 V only OLED? I suppose its vcc(OLED)-3v3(Nano).
Most OLEDs use 3.3V -5V where sometimes the 3.3V from the Arduino is not sufficient.
If its a 3.3V only OLED could you give the make of the OLED (does it have jumpers to change I2C address). Normaly the I2C scanner should return at least with nothing found.